# Why is there a time blank when I used rotateY(180deg)

Tags: javascript, css, animation, transform

Here is the test link: http://codepen.io/Gavin-YYC/pen/BpGOVd/.

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" name="button" class="button">test</button>
  <div class="pic-wall">
    <img src="test.jpg" alt="" data-back-pic="koi.jpg">
    <img src="test.jpg" alt="" data-back-pic="koi.jpg">
    <img src="test.jpg" alt="" data-back-pic="koi.jpg">
    <img src="test.jpg" alt="" data-back-pic="koi.jpg">
    <img src="test.jpg" alt="" data-back-pic="koi.jpg">
    <img src="test.jpg" alt="" data-back-pic="koi.jpg">
    <img src="test.jpg" alt="" data-back-pic="koi.jpg">
    <img src="test.jpg" alt="" data-back-pic="koi.jpg">
    <img src="test.jpg" alt="" data-back-pic="koi.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.pic-wall {
    perspective: 1400px;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.pic-wall .img-item {
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.pic-wall .img-item img {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.pic-wall .img-item img:nth-child(2) {
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotateY(-180deg);
}
.pic-wall .img-item.img-item-showback {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

When first load the page, then click the button 'test'.

You will find there is a blank for a while. Why？

Are there some error in my code?

Comment: works great in chrome

Comment: http://img.youthol.top/squire.gif  here is my case. Page load first，then click button 'test' only first time. I'm also test in chrome 56

Comment: http://img.youthol.top/QQ20170211-125221-HD.mp4

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to place the image inside a div element.

```
div.html('<div class="img-origin" ><img src="' + originPic + '"></div><div class="img-back"><img src="' + backPic + '"></div>');
```

Then modify css for that

```
.pic-wall .img-item div {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top : 0;
  left : 0;
}
.pic-wall .img-item div img{
  max-width : 100%;
}
.pic-wall .img-item .img-origin {

}
.pic-wall .img-item .img-back {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
.pic-wall .img-item.img-item-showback {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

And with some css cleanup, finally it looks like this.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/apQXZv?editors=0100

Comment: Thank you! I'll take your advice.

Comment: As i check the javascript code, instead of each original image, a `div` will be add including 2 img elements with two pictures set.. so your recom is not applicable in his scenario, please see my answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because of `backface-visibility: hidden` css you set!

> The backface-visibility property defines whether or not an element should be visible when not facing the screen.
>
> This property is useful when an element is rotated, and you do not want to see its backside.

just remove it to solve the issue:

```
.pic-wall .img-item img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /*backface-visibility: hidden;*/ /*remove this! */
}
```

**[see this code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZOrqm)**

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. I will read the manual carefully.